# We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now on detail page

Tags: cart

If someone want to add a product to the cart from the list view it works fine. But from a product detail page the Error appears:

We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.

Comment: check in your logs file, are you getting any error

Comment: Please see the exception log in the var/log directory add exception in your question

Comment: We need the error/exception, please go with your logs and print the exception

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced very same situation, and  it was because of 2 things mainly.

1. The write permission for the **generated** folder.
2. Still there was an issue with folder owner. The **generated** folder was under the ownership of root. When I changed that to Apache user, everything went smooth.

Comment: This was issue on my local, running mage 2.3

Answer (score 0):

1. check your error by firebug
2. check your error on var/log if can't see error on step 1
3. check data post to server when adding product to cart if can't see error on step 2 (make sure data post to server when adding new product is enought)

Comment: Delete Or Inactive Cart Price Rules from Admin

Answer (score -3):

This error comes because of caching problem.
So, enable the cache using

```
"php bin/magento cache:enable"
```

then it will work.

Comment: this is not a solution