# Add to cart functionality is not working for any product

Tags: addtocart, shopping-cart, cookie, permissions

my add to cart not working, its showing nothing in cart for 2 stores and for 1 store adding a default product everytime, doesn't matter which product we added,
its showing this exception....

***We can't add above item to cart.Please contact administratorThe product wasn't found. Verify the product and try again.***

i have checked my code is fine, its working on local setup and dev server, just issue is on production,

i have tried with cookie lifetime increase and permission settings on directories but none worked.. 
**do it need some more cookie or session changes which can be done ?**

**can any body share any idea or solution with some details ??**

Comment: try this solution `/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend and edit the file.php` Search for `'cache_dir' => null`, and replace it with `'cache_dir' => 'var/cache'`...

Comment: i have already tried this but not worked

Comment: after you are this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/235485/85907 ???

Comment: opposite to this link issue, mine is working on product detail page, but not working on List page. and regarding ownership: all directories already have www:data ownership

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to change in the domain as Magento 2 stores root URL in the third path without affecting the first version.

To resolve the issue, try to run additional SQL query:

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = REPLACE(value, '<old root URL or domain>', '<new root URL or domain>')
WHERE path = 'design/head/includes';
```

and then clear the cache by using this command:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

Hope it works for you.